# Particular form of the kernel of a positive matrix

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $\mathbf L$ be a positive ($L_{ij} \geqslant 0$) $k \times n$ matrix with $k < n$.

I'm looking for a matrix $\mathbf H \in \mathbb R^{n \times (n-k)}$ with two properties:

- columns of $\mathbf H$ form a basis in $\operatorname{ker} \mathbf L$:  $\mathbf{LH} = 0$ and $\operatorname{rank} \mathbf H = n - k$
- exists some permutation matrix $\mathbf Q \in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $\lambda \in \mathbb R$ that
  $$
  \mathbf {H} + \lambda \mathbf Q \begin{pmatrix}\mathbf I_{n-k}\\0\end{pmatrix} \geqslant 0
  $$

The last property requires that $\mathbf H$ should have only a few negative elements. Moreover each row and each column should have no more than one negative element.

*Example*. Let
$$
\mathbf L = \begin{pmatrix}
 1 & 2 & 3 & 4 \\
 4 & 3 & 2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
Then one can choose
$$
\mathbf {H} = \begin{pmatrix}
 2 & 1 \\
 -3 & -2 \\
 0 & 1 \\
 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
$$
This matrix satisfies the first property, but fails to satisfy the second, since it has two negative elements in the second row.

But
$$
\mathbf H' = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
 1 & -2 \\
 -2 & 1 \\
 1 & 0
\end{pmatrix}
= \mathbf {H} \begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0\\
-2 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$
satisfies both with 
$$
\lambda = 2\\
\mathbf Q = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
 0 & 0 & 0 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $H=0$ is a valid solution. On the other hand, it looks like if you take the kernel of $L$, then set the columns of $H$ to the corresponding basis vectors, you can negate them to make the diagonal entries of $H$ non-negative. Think of it this way, when you multiply matrices $AB$, the answer is $Ab_i$, where $b_i$ are the columns of $B$.

Comment: I've edited my question to clarify what I want from $\mathbf H$

Comment: @uranix: There's no point for the $Q,\lambda$ stuff because the fact that $H$ has at most one negative entry in each row,column implies the existence of $Q$ and $\lambda$, just pick $\lambda$ to be absurdly large and $Q$ to be the permutation matrix which picks out the negative entries of $H$.

Comment: @uranix: The new question isn't true, if I understand it correctly. Take a matrix whose kernal is spanned by $(1,1,-1,-1)^T$. Then $H$ will always have two negative numbers in the same column.

Comment: Yes, that is a counterexample. I'd weaken the requirements

Comment: Or I'd leave it as it is. Please add your example to the answer.